# How to get ZIP code using latitude and longitude in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to get the ZIP code for specific location using latitude and longitude?

How can i get it in PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need an external service that checks the geolocation against a registry that holds zipcodes. Maybe google has something like that? I know there are paid services that do similar things, though usually they retrieve addresses based on zipcodes, not the other way around.

Comment: Please check here: [PHP zipcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372223/get-zip-code-based-on-lat-long)

Answer (score 0):

Google is running some kind of geocoding, you should check it out,  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/
it might help you

Comment: I got the answer
$geocodeFromLatlon = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$model->latitude.','.$model->longitude.'&sensor=false');
 $output2 = json_decode($geocodeFromLatlon);
$addressComponents = $output2->results[0]->address_components;
 foreach($addressComponents as $addrComp){
                           if($addrComp->types[0] == 'postal_code'){
                               $current_location_zipcode =  $addrComp->long_name;
                           }
                       }